# Are chisel3.util.Queue `full` `maybe_full` signals unaccessible external to the queue module?

Tags: chisel

I tried accessing `maybe_full` and `full` directly, but since the error is `'Bool (Reg in Queue)' is not visible from the current module`, I assume these signals are only internal to Queue? Will I need to customize the queue util if I want to make these outputs for my module?

Comment: That is correct. Those signals are not part of the public API of `chisel3.util.Queue`.